# abntex2 + xwatermark = already defined command erros

Tags: framed, xwatermark, abntex2

Look at this tiny code:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}
\usepackage{xwatermark}
\begin{document}
Testing 1 2 3
\end{document}
```

It produces the following errors in TexnicCenter 2.02 (64 bits), ran with up to date MiKTeX distribution:

```
Command \framed already defined 
Command \shaded already defined 
Command \leftbar already defined 
Command \snugshade already defined 
Extra \endgroup
```

Someone know why that happens and how to fix it?

NOTE: I ran the code in Overleaf and no error was shown there.

Comment: `xwatermark` depends on `catoptions`, which is currently broken

Comment: Yes, [I see](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/latex3/latex2e/411/708434918). So, it would be advisable to move to a similar package?

Comment: Take a look at that [issue on github](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/411).  A few workarounds were given.  I think I'd go for [this one](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/411#issuecomment-714463578)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Instead, I preferred to get rid of xwatermark and adopt draftwatermark.

Comment: Suit yourself.  The answer I linked uses LaTeX's new hooks, so no packages required (but might not work in Overleaf for the time being).  Please, do write an answer here later, so other people can have another option

Comment: I would strongly advice you to use the package `eso-pic` instead. I had some issues with `xwatermark` while mixing it with `ABNT` and `hyperref`. `eso-pic` is much more reliable, less problematic and more flexible than `xwatermark`.

Answer (score 3):

Tried the solutions of [this link](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/411) suggested by [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) but all resulted on errors. Solution: get rid of xwatermark and replace it by draftwatermark (no errors when compiling in TexnicCenter):

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\SetWatermarkText{Draft}
\DraftwatermarkOptions{
    color={[gray]0.5},
    angle=45,
    hpos=0.5\paperwidth,vpos=0.5\paperheight,
    scale=5
}

\begin{document}
Testing 1 2 3
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses [eso-pci](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) and `tikz` to create some watermarks.
`Tikz` is used to create texts with opacity but can also be used to insert images (for example in [tikz-among-us](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-among-us.))

The following example applies some variations of watermarks that can be made with `eso-pic`.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% -----------------------------------------
% Boxes with translucent texts
% -----------------------------------------
\newsavebox\myboxr\savebox\myboxr{\tikz[color=red!80 ,opacity=0.4]\node{\huge{\textbf{red}}};}
\newsavebox\myboxo\savebox\myboxo{\tikz[color=orange!80 ,opacity=0.4]\node{\huge{\textbf{orange}}};}
\newsavebox\myboxy\savebox\myboxy{\tikz[color=yellow!90!black ,opacity=0.4]\node{\huge{\textbf{yellow}}};}
\newsavebox\myboxg\savebox\myboxg{\tikz[color=green!80!black!80,opacity=0.4]\node{\huge{\textbf{green}}};}

% -----------------------------------------
% FrontGround and BackGround watermarks
% -----------------------------------------
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{\put(0,-250){\scalebox{10}{\rotatebox{45}{\usebox\myboxr}}}}%
  \AtPageCenter{\put(-280,-210){\scalebox{5}{\rotatebox{30}{\usebox\myboxy}}}}%
  \AtStockLowerLeft{\put(250,150){\scalebox{5}{\rotatebox{90}{\color{blue}{blue}}}}}%
  
}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{\put(-70,-200){\scalebox{10}{\rotatebox{-45}{\usebox\myboxo}}}}%
  \AtPageCenter{\put(-100,50){\scalebox{7}{\rotatebox{-30}{\usebox\myboxg}}}}%
  \AtStockLowerLeft{\put(420,350){\scalebox{5}{\rotatebox{-90}{\color{violet}{violet}}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}

\lipsum[66]

\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

The result follows:

[image]